# WebLogic 12.1.2 Domain Creation Error

Tags: weblogic

I installed WebLogic 12.1.2 on my Windows 7 64-bit machine using Java 7.  The installation was successful, but I'm running into the following error when attempting to create a new domain.  It worked on a similar computer I did this on earlier today so it must be something about this particular machine.  Any ideas on what the problem may be?

```
    2015-07-14 20:23:42,509 INFO  [AWT-EventQueue-0] com.oracle.cie.wizard.help.DefaultHelpProvider - Initializing help implementation....
    2015-07-14 20:23:42,759 INFO  [AWT-EventQueue-0] com.oracle.cie.domain.DomainLoader - domain C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\learn is not a valid BEA domain
    2015-07-14 20:23:42,759 INFO  [AWT-EventQueue-0] com.oracle.cie.domain.DomainRegistryWrapper - need to initialize domainRegistrydocument object
    2015-07-14 20:23:42,759 INFO  [AWT-EventQueue-0] com.oracle.cie.domain.DomainLoader - domain C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\learn is not a valid BEA domain
    2015-07-14 20:24:33,597 INFO  [AWT-EventQueue-0] com.oracle.cie.domain.AbstractTemplate - Setting symbol for component oracle.wls.core.app.server version 12.1.2.0.0 to oracle.wls.core.app.server_12.1.2.0.0/wlserver_ORACLE_HOME
    2015-07-14 20:24:33,612 INFO  [AWT-EventQueue-0] com.oracle.cie.domain.AbstractTemplate - Setting symbol for component oracle.wls.core.app.server version 12.1.2.0.0 to oracle.wls.core.app.server_12.1.2.0.0/wlserver_ORACLE_HOME
    2015-07-14 20:25:11,741 WARNING [AWT-EventQueue-0] com.oracle.cie.domain.gui.panel.ConfigVPanel - Ajusted ordering index 5 is out of bounds.
    2015-07-14 20:25:11,741 WARNING [AWT-EventQueue-0] com.oracle.cie.domain.gui.panel.ConfigVPanel - Ajusted ordering index 6 is out of bounds.
    2015-07-14 20:25:11,741 WARNING [AWT-EventQueue-0] com.oracle.cie.domain.gui.panel.ConfigVPanel - Ajusted ordering index 7 is out of bounds.
    2015-07-14 20:25:19,962 SEVERE [Thread-7] com.oracle.cie.domain.DomainGenerator - Domain Creation Failed!

    Domain Location: C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\learn

    Reason: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: CN

    Exception:

    java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: CN

    java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: CN
        at com.oracle.cie.security.impl.BCSecurityHandlerImpl.generateSubjectPrincipal(BCSecurityHandlerImpl.java:214)
        at com.oracle.cie.security.impl.BCSecurityHandlerImpl.generateV3Certificate(BCSecurityHandlerImpl.java:79)
        at com.oracle.cie.security.impl.BCSecurityHandlerImpl.sign(BCSecurityHandlerImpl.java:60)
        at com.oracle.cie.security.impl.BaseSecurityHandler.initDefaultKeyStore(BaseSecurityHandler.java:94)
        at com.oracle.cie.domain.security.WLSSecurityHelper.createDefaultKeyStores(WLSSecurityHelper.java:66)
        at com.oracle.cie.domain.DomainGenerator.run(DomainGenerator.java:468)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    2015-07-14 20:27:51,631 INFO  [AWT-EventQueue-0] com.oracle.cie.common.util.BrowserLauncher - jdk used is : 1.7.0_51
```

Comment: `wlserver_ORACLE_HOME` seems to be the key... It's like the weblogic install script has no idea where weblogic is actually installed/your env is wrong. Compare your environment variables on the host that worked to the one that fails?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was an issue related to a change I made to the java.security file within my JDK for another project I was working on earlier this year.  That change brought in a version of Bouncy Castle that does not agree with WebLogic 12.1.2, which apparently expects an older version of that library.  The solution for me was to reinstall the JDK entirely to back out my change.